# How to pair a symbol CS3070 bluetooth scanner with a nexus 7 (2013) tablet

Tags: nexus-7, troubleshooting, bluetooth-pairing

The pairing code asks me to type on the device which has no keys.  Is there a work around?

Answer (score 2):

You don't type.  You scan in barcodes of the numbers you need.

See step 6 of [this guide](http://www.motorolasolutions.com/web/Business/Product%20Lines/Symbol/Symbol%20Bar%20Code%20Scanners/_Documents/CS3070_Tablet_Pairing_Guide.pdf) for the barcodes.  These barcodes can also be found on page 1-21 of the manual.